# SVG не растягивается на весь блок

Tags: html, css, svg, видео

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть блок с видео над видео svg-изображение, но svg не закрывает весь блок и оставляет щели.
Есть ли способ это поправить ?

p.s. Пробовал с помощью псевдоэлементов закрыть щели но это так себе вариант.

```
<div class="directions__video">     
    <div class="directions__video-container">
         <div class="directions__video-container-in">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="620" height="620" viewBox="0 0 620 620" fill="none">
                   <path class="svg-move-circle" d="M0 0V620H620V0H0ZM359.582 615.0966C155.4172 611.9119 1.3701 447.1727 2.3348 285.9819C-0.3652 121.0493 148.015 -7.4427 311.6799 2.6018C502.8146 14.7151 614.1982 151.6778 617.0649 349.8435C623.6315 570.3759 483.1004 615.0728 359.582 615.0966Z" fill="#002D6D"></path>
              </svg>
             <video src="/uploads/storage/6b/4b/2e6733189ccce556fae7f216faaa9e93f595e03c.mp4#t=0.5" width="1300" height="100%" autoplay="" playsinline="" loop="" muted="" poster="/render/storage/26/a8/b5158d9c49737fba410e1b9f72d721a8a8a68b8d.jpg"></video>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Cтили:

```
.directions__video {
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 75px;
}
.directions__video-container {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-flex;
}
.directions__video-container-in {
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}
.directions__video-container svg {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 5;
}
.directions__video-container video {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Судя по картинке, нужно использовать или _mask_ или _clip-path_

Comment: ширину и высоту уберите из тега svg

Comment: Clip-path начально использовали но на iOS не работает с video (свг не отображается).
Удалив ширину и высоту картина не меняется.

Comment: Что-то какое-то кривое кольцо, очень много цифр после точки, они, наверное, и дают искажение. Можно же округлить. Ну и чтобы совсем уверенным быть, можно якорные точки немного за пределы viewbox вывести. `d="M -1 -1 L -1 621 L 621 621 L 621 -1 L -1 -1 Z M 360 615 C 155 612 1 447 2 286 C 0 121 148 -7 312 3 C 503 15 614 152 617 350 C 624 570 483 615 360 615 Z"`

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qBQaWbz  вот так же растягивается на весь экран

Comment: Вариант работает если без жестких ограничений контейнера.
https://codepen.io/arnich/pen/dyQpVRy если ограничить и развернуть на большие экраны (к примеру 2200) то щели появятся снова.

Comment: Разцмеется 2200 будут щели, свг на то и резиновое что бы не иметь ограничения

Comment: Вы сами подумайте, на улицах билоборды 6 на 4 метра делают и нету ни каких косяков....кривизна подобного изображения зависит от того кто делает...виноват не свг

Comment: С img такого бага нет. На любом разрешение без щелей.

Comment: На mask css будет работать без нареканий

Comment: А пример можно с mask? Я не особо с свг дружу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При воспроизведении вашего кода не заметны нестыковки SVG маски и подложенного слоя видео. В принцине можно сделать SVG слой чуть больше на 1 % по ширине и высоте. А слой видео чуть меньше и спозиционировать со смещением, чтобы устранить погрешность наложения слоев. Код прилагаю.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="directions__video">     
            <div class="directions__video-container">
                 <div class="directions__video-container-in">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="620" height="620" viewBox="0 0 620 620" fill="none">
                           <path class="svg-move-circle" d="M0 0V620H620V0H0ZM359.582 615.0966C155.4172 611.9119 1.3701 447.1727 2.3348 285.9819C-0.3652 121.0493 148.015 -7.4427 311.6799 2.6018C502.8146 14.7151 614.1982 151.6778 617.0649 349.8435C623.6315 570.3759 483.1004 615.0728 359.582 615.0966Z" fill="#002D6D"></path>
                      </svg>
                     <video src="/uploads/storage/6b/4b/2e6733189ccce556fae7f216faaa9e93f595e03c.mp4#t=0.5" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="" playsinline="" loop="" muted="" poster="/render/storage/26/a8/b5158d9c49737fba410e1b9f72d721a8a8a68b8d.jpg"></video>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #012d6d;
            }
            .directions__video {
               position: relative;
               margin-right: 75px;
                background: #012d6d;    
            }
            .directions__video-container {
               position: relative;
               display: inline-flex;
            }
            .directions__video-container-in {
               overflow: hidden;
               display: flex;
               width: 100%;
               height: 100%;
               position: relative;
            }
            .directions__video-container svg {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 5;
                width: 101%;
                height: 101%;
            }
            .directions__video-container video {
                position: absolute;
                top: 1px;
                left: calc(50% - 2px);
                transform: translateX(-50%);
                background: red;
                width: calc(100% - 5px);
                height: calc(100% - 5px);
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S.
В книге "[Векторная графика для начинающих: теория и практика технического дизайна](https://www.litres.ru/book/e-u-polyakov/vektornaya-grafika-dlya-nachinauschih-teoriya-i-praktika-tehn-68397985/)" есть пошаговое решение как работать с многослойной иллюстрацией, включая SVG маски для обрамления композиции + псевдоклассы слоев с глубиной z-index. Посмотрите там решение с кодом.